# how to handle an integer field with LINQ using c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have received a data table from the SQL server
and for now, I want to show those records that "vocId" is equal to 1.
but the following code represents all records.
what can I do to fix it?

[image]

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 DataTable dtFetch = new DataTable();

 dt = cls.sentencesFetch();

 var result = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
              where r.Field<int>("vocId").ToString() == 1.ToString()
              select r;
 DataView view = result.AsDataView();
 dtFetch = view.Table;
 dgv.DataSource = dtFetch;
```

Comment: Why are you using "ToString()"?    Why are you using view.Table?  Try following : dgv.DataSource = null; DataTable resultTable = result.CopyToDataTable(); dgv.DataSource = resultTable;

Comment: have you tried using the debugger? what does result return?

Comment: Doesn't `view.Table` return the original source data? Been a hundred years since I've had to deal with this old `DataSet` stuff. Why can't you just do `dgv.DataSource = view`?

Comment: it has been fixed with the following code:
``` DataView view = result.AsDataView();  
dgv.DataSource = view;
```` 
but why haven't work my previous code?